# Cordova Statusbar / Notifications

Tags: android, ios, cordova, statusbar

I'm sorry for asking something probably this basic, but since I've never programmed for native android or iOS, only with cordova, I don't even know how to search for this.

How can I add an icon to Android and iOS status bar? And when the status bar is open, how to add a line that once clicked leads to my app?

EDIT: Actually, it looks like "notification bar" is the name I'm looking for